# Wildcard CNAME record for wildcard domain

Tags: dns

Suppose I own a wildcard domain like `*.example.com` that points at `192.0.2.34`

All requests to `https://bob.example.com` will point at the server `192.0.2.34`.

Is there a way that I can also have a wildcard CNAME that points `*.bob.stuff.com` at the `192.0.2.34` server?

Basically I'd like a double wildcard domain so I can do `apps.bob.example.com` and `blarg.bob.example.com` and have all of those resolutions point at `192.0.2.34` over SSL.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do a "double" wildcard, in the sense that `*.*.example.com` will not work as expected in the zone.

You can however put both `*.example.com` and `*.bob.example.com` in your zone, the later will override the former, and you can repeat that for any other string than `bob`.

See https://serverfault.com/questions/942124/can-i-use-nested-dns-wildcard-records for a similar example.